# How do I add a column of numbers which are in the same row as a date that is less than or equal to Today()?

Tags: excel

In Cells A1:A4 I have Dates. In Cells B1:B4 I have numbers. In C1 I have todays date. I want in Column D1 the sum of all the values in B which have a corresponding date in column A that is less than or equal to the date in C1. For example:

```
     A           B      C          D
1   6.6.13      300    8.6.13     512
2   7.6.13      200     
3   8.6.13       12   
4   9.6.13        5
```

D1 Should be calculated by a formula. How can I achieve this with a formula. I have tried

```
=SUMIF(A1:A4;<=C1;B1:B4)
```

but it seems to not be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The if condition has to be in quotes; try the following:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A4;"<="&C1;B1:B4)
```

Comment: Great. This works. Can you explain what teh & is for the &C1?

Comment: It concatenates the string "<=" and the value from C1 together, so that the final string is "<=(value of C1)". This is needed instead of "<=C1" because that would be checking against the string "C1" and not the value from the field C1.